# Why is custom UINavigationController not presenting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I am making a custom `UINavigationController` which uses a custom `UICollectionViewController` as its root view controller. All is done programmatically, because I am fitting all these controllers into a framework (I'm using iOS 8). But when I tried to present the `UINavigationController` using `presentViewController:animated:` and `navigationController?.pushViewController:animated:`, it doesn't show up, and the view controller which it is supposed to be covering if shown freezes. Here's the code for the custom `UINavigationController`:

```
public class BlahBlahCustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var rootCollectionViewController: BlahBlahCustomCollectionViewController!

    public init() {
        rootCollectionViewController = BlahBlahCustomCollectionViewController()
        super.init(rootViewController: rootCollectionViewController)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)

        rootCollectionViewController = BlahBlahCustomCollectionViewController()
        setViewControllers([rootCollectionViewController], animated: false)
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    //No code other than above
}
```

And here is the code for the `BlahBlahCustomCollectionViewController`:

```
public class BlahBlahCustomCollectionViewController {
    //...

    public init() {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)

        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        title = ""
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    //...
}
```

The code that I used to present `BlahBlahCustomNavigationController` is simply `presentViewController(MultiSelectImagePickerController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`.

I have looked up sample code and all that stuff, but the way the sample code has hooked up their `UINavigationController`s and `UICollectionViewController`s is the same as mine, but why aren't my view controller appearing? Could you pinpoint what is wrong? Thanks! ;P

Comment: Have you set the initial view controller?

Comment: @Wingzero I am presenting the custom UINavigationController in a view controller that is already on screen.

Comment: Since the problem seems to be with the presentation, you need to show the method where you do the presentation, don't you think?.

Comment: @rdelmar Ok, thanks. The method is just a simple `presentViewController(MultiSelectImagePickerController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`